# HTML align last column right

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a problem. For my current project I have a page with a list. The list contains posts, which is shown in a `css grid`. The last 2 columns of the grid need to be `text-aligned` to the right, but that isn't working. Here is the code snippet:

```css
mat-form-field {
    margin: 0px 10px;
}

/**
 * Add basic flex styling so that the cells evenly space themselves in the row.
 */
mat-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.profile-picture-container {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.profile-picture-container > img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.fa-play {
    color: white;
}

#btnToggleAudio {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 10000;
}

mat-list-item {
    flex: 1;
}

.header {
    font-weight: bold;
}

h3 {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.item-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 60px 40% 20% 20% 20%;
    align-items: center;
}

.item-grid > div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.right {
    text-align: right;
}

mat-list-item:hover {
    background-color: #c4c4c4;
}

mat-list-item:hover #profile-picture {
    filter: brightness(70%);
}

mat-list-item:hover #btnToggleAudio {
    display: block;
}

.action-button{
    height: 30px!important;
    width: 50px!important;
    min-width: unset!important;
}

.mat-icon-align {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .item-grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 50% 25% 25%;
    }

    .desktop-only {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<mat-list>
    <h3 matHeader>Reported posts</h3>
    <mat-list-item>
        <div matLine>
            <div class="item-grid" matline>
                <div class="profile-picture-container" style="grid-row: 1 / 3">
                    <img id="profile-picture" src="/assets/images/post_city.jpg">
                    <button id="btnToggleAudio" (click)="onDismissClick(1)">
                        <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="header">Title</div>
                <div class="header desktop-only">Username</div>
                <div class="header right">Reports</div>
                <div class="header right" style="background-color: blue">Actions</div>
                <div>Test post</div>
                <div class="desktop-only">Dummy-2000</div>
                <div class="right">3</div>
                <div class="right" style="background-color: blue">
                    <button mat-button class="action-button right">
                        <mat-icon class="mat-icon-align">check_circle</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <button mat-button class="action-button right">
                        <mat-icon class="mat-icon-align">delete</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
</mat-list>
```

As you can see, the reports and the actions are not aligned to the right, while they all contain the class `right`. Also, the icons in the action buttons are not perfectly centered as shown below:
[image]

You can see the background color of the upper delete button changed a bit. The icons are more to the bottom-right. I tried to align them with the class: `.mat-icon-align`, but this is not perfectly centered.

How can I get these 2 things to work?

### UPDATE

Using `justify-content: flex-end;` results in the following:
[image]

At the end of the grid, the last column goes outside the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change

```
.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

to

```
.right {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

When working with `flex-box` and `grid` changes the way that the browser distributes the space of the contents inside.  Your issue is that the `div`'s with the class `.right` aren't the full width of the cell.  `justify-content: flex-end;` on the class will push the content to the far right like you're asking for.

Comment: The last column with action buttons will fall out of the screen then.... Check update

Comment: It's getting cut off because your `.item-grid` has a total with of 100% + 60px.  One quick way to fix this is to change your `grid-template-columns: 60px 40% 20% 20% 20%;` to `grid-template-columns: 60px calc(40% - 60px) 20% 20% 20%;`

Comment: Ah, totally forgot that :( Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: No problem! :) Glad I could help